# Doctrine array type in Entity and MySQL (Symfony2)

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to work with Roles users in my Entity User Doctrine for backend engine. My authentification work correctly if I fixed static role in entity but if I want to retrieve that from my BDD MySQL I have a unserialize error.

My MySQL Field is in a Text (or Longtext) types and contain just one role like this : "ROLE_ADMIN" or "ROLE_USER". I have tried same think with field like this "ADMIN" or "USER" but nothing change.

Can you tell me why my retrieve Roles bug please ?

gist : [Entity User Doctrine gist here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e88caba1a22a3885f267)

Comment: What is the full error that you are getting?

Comment: graphical feedback on web browser is : ContextErrorException : Notice: unserialize() : Error at offset 0 of 5bytes in ArrayType.php

Comment: I have reload my entity in DB but the error is the same. in symfony code this is this line : $val = unserialize($value);

Comment: How are you setting the roles?  `$entity->setRoles(array('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER'));`?

Comment: no because I just import from MySQL. My data is already present in DB.

Comment: What does the data in the DB look like? Its likely that the data in there isnt valid and thats why you are getting the error

Comment: I try "ADMIN" or "ROLE_ADMIN" or "USER" or "ROLE_USER" but nothing run correctly. all the same error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48615/discussion-between-chausser-and-miltone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solve lot of problems with serialize or deserialize the good way is work with fixtures data and encode those directly.

The deserialisation proceed run correctly without error because you encode your data with specific encodage php symfony code.

For first time, this is not very efficient to complete your database in SQL query directly.